# Facebook connect in Blackberry application

Tags: facebook, integration

I want to integrate facebook like button to my blackberry application.I'm using facebook Blackberry SDK. Does any one has idea as to how do i got about that.

Answer (score 0):

Download graph api from http://sourceforge.net/projects/facebook-bb-sdk/. After that you have to add two thinks.

one is when you want to post a photo to your friends wall ,you have to put one more key-value in the JSONObject(Request) - that is requestObject.put("target_id",getid()) in publisePhoto method facebookuser.java & facebook.java

Second is you have to change JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos", requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);

to

JSONObject responseObject = fb.write(getId() + "/photos?access_token="+Facebook.token, requestObject, pPhoto.getMIMEType(), imageData, true);in FacebookUser.java & Facebook.java

where token is Static string from Facebook.java and store the value of access_token (you have to add it)

thanks 
parag