# Blackberry Facebook like button

Tags: blackberry, facebook-like

Оn the site there are articles that have facebook like button. I'm trying to write a blackberry client for it, and I can not understand how to implement like button. I tried facebook-bb-sdk from [Facebook connect in Blackberry application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4519427/facebook-connect-in-blackberry-application) and BrowserField but have not yet succeeded. How to realize like?